# JFreeChart: LogarithmicAxis with normal ticks

Tags: java, jfreechart

This is how my x axis looks using `NumberAxis`:
[image: Number axis]

This is how it looks like using a `LogarithmicAxis`:
[image: Log axis]

I want the logarithmic axis to display numbered ticks with a distance of 5 like with the number axis, but retain the logarithmic scale. How do I do that? I tried various methods of `LogarithmicAxis`, but none of them seem to help.

Comment: You might compare your approach to the [mcve] examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097313/230513).